# Intersection of $n$-dimensional minimal surfaces with two-dimensional planes

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

Let $M^n \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+k}$ be a smoothly embedded minimal surface. When the dimension is $n = 2$ and the codimension is $k = 1$ the intersection of $M$ with planes is well understood. If $M$ and a plane $\Pi$ meet tangentially at a point $p \in M$, then locally near $p$, the intersection $M \cap \Pi$ is a union of finitely many smooth arcs meeting at $p$. (Unless $M = \Pi$ of course.) Moreover there is an even number of arcs, and they meet at equal angles; the number of arcs is determined by Almgren's frequency.

> Is there a similar description for a tangential intersection $M \cap \Pi$, when the dimension of $M$ is arbitrary, but $\Pi$ remains two-dimensional?

Comment: By tangential intersection, do you just mean that $T_p\Pi \subseteq T_p M$? What are the sorts of results you are hoping for? Also, are you still fixing $k = 1$?

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, that's what I had in mind. I am happy to fix $k = 1$ if this makes the question more tractable, but I'm not sure it helps much. Regarding the sort of results I would be interested in: if for example the same description were possible for generic $\Pi \subset T_p M$, or else maybe something like $\mathcal{H}^1(M \cap \Pi) = 0$ unless $M$ is translation-invariant in $\Pi$? I am honestly not even sure what a conservative vs. optimistic version would be.